# Clojure clj-orient: Update values of vertex in graph-db

Tags: graph, clojure, orientdb

I am trying to familiarise myself with **clj-orient**'s graph database. It's very easy to create graphs and link items. Now I want to do the following:

1. find a vertex by its properties (let's say I created a vertex type `:person` and I'm looking for the one with `:name "Bob"`. I do that by `(let [bob (first (oq/native-query :person {:name "Bob"})])` (oq being the .query namespace)
2. now I want to make the db know that Bob likes animals by adding a key-value pair. I tried to do that with `clj-orient.core/update-prop!` but couldn't figure out how to do that. Is it even the right function?
3. similar to that, how could I change the value of an existing property?

clj-orient's documentation is a bit spartanic at best, so I'm not sure if I don't understand or just can't find the appropriate methods. Can anybody help me with a bit of example code?

**edit:** I know I could use

```
(oq/clj-command! '{:update :person :set {:likes "animals"} :where [(= :name "Bob")]})
```

but in my oppinion I would lose all speed benefits of using a graph db because this would parse all :persons every time I modify anything.